# Django ArrayField - Choices from a class of constants - ERROR fields.E005

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have a file with constants declared inside classes:

```
class LanguageChoices:
    EN = "English"
    FR = "French"

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return (
            (cls.EN, _("English")),
            (cls.FR, _("French")),
        )
```

And my models:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from apps.users.constants import LanguageChoices

class Data(models.Model):
    language = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(
            max_length=30, choices=LanguageChoices.choices()), 
            blank=True, null=True
        )
    )
```

When I try to run migrations it run into this error (this happens even if I erase all previous migration files and use a new database):

SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

```
ERRORS:
users.Data.language: (postgres.E001) Base field for array has errors:
    'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples. (fields.E005)
ERROR: 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out the code is good, there was a little comma after one of the values (like EN = "English",) right in the middle. VSCode pulled no warns and my vision played me some tricks and had hide it from me.